# Give IPV6 internet to a device through another device

Tags: ipv6, bridge, gateway

I have two devices, a laptop and a raspberry pi. I don't want to use wifi on the raspberry pi, and I my router provides only an ipv6 address. So here are the physical connections I have:

```
Router <---(wifi ipv6)---> Laptop <---(ethernet)---> Raspberry pi
```

Usually with ipv4 I just do:

```
# First machine:
sudo ip addr add 192.168.12.01 dev eth0
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1

#Second machine:
sudo ip addr add 192.168.12.02 dev eth0
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.12.01 dev eth0
```

And then I can ping google for example:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

However, this does not work on IPv6. Why, and what is/are the proper solution(s)?

Answer (score 0):

In this answer, I'll call the first router the "main router", the Laptop will be the "middle router", and the raspberry pi will be the client. Moreover, I'll use the following names for the interfaces:

```
Main router <---(wifi)--->[interface wlo1] Middle router [interface eno2]<---(ethernet)--->[interface eth0] Client
```

So apparently the thing I tried above does not work because in ipv6 a machine having an IP contained in the subnet needs to be on the same link as the one connected to the main router. So, if I trust [this website](https://lafibre.info/ipv6/deleguer-un-prefixe-64-ipv6-pour-le-point-dacces-wifi/48/) (sorry it's french), there is only 4 ways to cascade two ipv6 routers:

- either we use DHCPv6-PD if the main router support it, but very few routers does
- either the main router can add a static route to the second router. Same, very few routers support it.
- either we setup on the middle router a NDP Proxy (works fairly well)
- either we setup on the middle router a NAT IPv6 (really not recommended)

So in this answer, I'll use the 3rd option, based on NDP Proxy. All the credits goes to this (french again) [website](https://linux-attitude.fr/post/proxy-ndp-ipv6).

## Determine IP addresses

Using `ip -6 a` on the middle router and on the main router, you can see which ipv6 you have (take the global one, *not* the link one that starts with `fe80`). In the following, we assume that:

- `2a04:1234:5678:abcd::ae` is the ip of the main router
- `2a04:1234:5678:abcd:24ff:7532:8b2c:aeba/64` is the ip of the main router

Because you have a `/64`, it means that if you want a subnet, you cannot change the first 64 bits (i.e. any subnet needs to start with `2a04:1234:5678:abcd`). So let's choose a subnet for the client, for example:

- `2a04:1234:5678:abcd:0001::/80` will be the address/network of the client, and is an arbitrary subnet.

## Useless part

So first, I don't think if it necessary, but I decided to disable network manager on the ethernet interface for the middle router, which require a few commands. Maybe try first without that part, and if it fails come back here.

```
[me@middleRouter:~]$ nmcli dev set eno2 managed no
## Check
[me@middleRouter:~]$ nmcli dev status
```

Then, check what are your ip:

```
[me@middleRouter:~]$ ip -6 a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2a04:1234:5678:abcd:e0a1:98fd:80d1:4b1f/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 3053sec preferred_lft 3053sec
    inet6 2a04:1234:5678:abcd:24ff:7532:8b2c:aeba/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 3053sec preferred_lft 3053sec
    inet6 fe80::5555:6666:7777:b9e6/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

[me@middleRouter:~]$ ip -6 route
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2a04:1234:5678:abcd::/64 dev wlo1 proto ra metric 600 pref medium
2a04:1234:5678:abcd::/64 dev wlo1 metric 1024 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlo1 proto kernel metric 600 pref medium
default via fe80::1111:2222:3333:5add dev wlo1 proto ra metric 600 pref high
```

As you can see my interface `eno2` does not have a local link ipv6, so I will manually add one, but if you have a link ipv6 you can skip that part (and apparently, you could put any value for the local link as soon as it starts with `fe80`, but let's use the value derived from the MAC address):

```
[me@middleRouter:~]$ ipv6calc --in prefix+mac fe80:: c0:3e:ba:68:01:09
No action type specified, try autodetection...found type: prefixmac2ipv6
fe80::c23e:baff:fe68:0109
[me@middleRouter:~]$ sudo ip addr add fe80::c23e:baff:fe68:0109 dev eno2
```

Now, you can see that we have a link ip on both interfaces:

```
[me@middleRouter:~]$ ip -6 a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::c23e:baff:fe68:0109/128 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2a04:1234:5678:abcd:e0a1:98fd:80d1:4b1f/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 3581sec preferred_lft 3581sec
    inet6 2a04:1234:5678:abcd:24ff:7532:8b2c:aeba/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 3581sec preferred_lft 3581sec
    inet6 fe80::5555:6666:7777:b9e6/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

## Enable forwarding and Proxy NDP

On the middle router, run:

```
[me@middleRouter:~]$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.eno2.forwarding=1
net.ipv6.conf.eno2.forwarding = 1

[me@middleRouter:~]$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.wlo1.forwarding=1
net.ipv6.conf.wlo1.forwarding = 1

[me@middleRouter:~]$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.eno2.proxy_ndp=1
net.ipv6.conf.eno2.proxy_ndp = 1

[me@middleRouter:~]$ sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.wlo1.proxy_ndp=1
net.ipv6.conf.wlo1.proxy_ndp = 1
```

## Configure the route/ip of the client

We can add the ip address, and add routes:

```
[rasp@client:~]$ sudo ip route add 2a04:1234:5678:abcd::ae/64 dev eth0


[rasp@client:~]$ sudo ip route add default via 2a04:1234:5678:abcd::ae

[rasp@client:~]$ sudo ip address add 2a04:1234:5678:abcd:1::/80 dev eth0

[rasp@client:~]$ ip -6 a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2a04:1234:5678:abcd:1::/80 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:feea:f6ce/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

[rasp@client:~]$ ip -6 route
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2a04:1234:5678:abcd:1::/80 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2a04:1234:5678:abcd::/64 dev eth0 metric 1024 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via 2a04:1234:5678:abcd::ae dev eth0 metric 1024 pref medium
```

## Add the routes of the middle router, and the proxy

Now on the middle router:

```
[me@middleRouter:~]$ sudo ip route add 2a04:1234:5678:abcd:0001::/80 dev eno2

## Configure the ndp proxy: /!\ the interface is the one that needs to
## have access to the ip, not the one that contains the ip!
[me@middleRouter:~]$ sudo ip neigh add proxy 2a04:1234:5678:abcd::ae dev eno2

[me@middleRouter:~]$ sudo ip neigh add proxy 2a04:1234:5678:abcd:1:: dev wlo1

### You may need to enable the promiscuous mode to make sure the router does not miss the packages that are not made for him direclty:
[me@middleRouter:~]$ sudo ifconfig eno2 promisc

[me@middleRouter:~]$ sudo ifconfig wlo1 promisc
```

## Enjoy, or debug

Now, you can check it works by pinging a google ip:

```
[rasp@client:~]$ ping 2a00:1450:4007:812::2003
PING 2a00:1450:4007:812::2003(2a00:1450:4007:812::2003) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2a00:1450:4007:812::2003: icmp_seq=1 ttl=113 time=43.8 ms
64 bytes from 2a00:1450:4007:812::2003: icmp_seq=2 ttl=113 time=34.8 ms
64 bytes from 2a00:1450:4007:812::2003: icmp_seq=3 ttl=113 time=65.7 ms
^C
--- 2a00:1450:4007:812::2003 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 34.808/48.098/65.684/12.965 ms
```

If it does not work, `wireshark` or `tcpdump -ni <interface> ip6` could be useful to debug.

Finally, if you want to be able to use domain names, you can add DNS with adding a nameserver line to `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Generated by resolvconf
options edns0
nameserver 2001:4860:4860::8888
```

Comment: I should note that these "only 4" ways are...the same as with IPv4. (Actually IPv4 doesn't have a PD equivalent, but it does have ARP proxying, static routes, and NAT all the same.) I'm quite sure option #4 - NAT - is what made your own v4 example work, as well.